# How do I get dogs to stop chronically barking?

Tags: technology, substitute-tool, comfort

I have a neighbor that never shuts up their hunting dogs, and they bark constantly day and night. Is there a device or life hack to make dogs shut up?

I would like to try more passive approaches to get them to stop barking without disturbing their owner because they do not care.

I tried talking to the neighbors and he said they are hunting dogs and to try to get them to stop barking would mess with their training. So I am going to try to find a sonic devise that only the dogs can hear. I don't care about if the dogs hunt good if my peace and liberty is being violated.

Any ideas on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try a dog whistle. Blow it when they bark. They will learn that when they bark that they will be annoyed by the whistle and hopefully stop. There are ultrasonic anti barking devices out there if you have the money.

Answer (score 5):

The key is whether your neighbor wants to try to stop the barking or not. I presume you've mentioned this to the neighbor already - trying to stop someone else's dog from barking is not practical, what you need to do is convince the neighbor to stop their own dog barking. In some locations there are bylaws against it and you can phone and report it, and someone will come by and speak to the owner.

When I was a child, the neighbor dogs barked at night but whenever my dad talked to them about it, they said "oh no, our dogs don't bark." So whenever the dogs barked, he would call their house and just say "the dogs are barking." This worked - I don't know if they brought them in at night or what, but they knew if the dogs woke our house, our house was going to wake their house. No swearing, no threatening, just letting them know about the barking.

The precise approach you take will depend on your neighbor. But do not take any direct action towards the dogs. They are not yours to train.

Comment: If that is not an option then what?

Comment: You are looking for a way, from a distance, from your home, to cause someone else's dogs to stop barking without ever discussing it with the owner of the dogs, or getting that person involved?

Comment: Yes a passive aggressive approach. a very loud ultra sonic devise that activates when his dogs start barking works well. I can't hear nor should he:)